# FindingViewById of Elements belonging to different activity

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been wondering if Xamarin has support for this. This is how i have structured my application. I have a CardView(list.axml) in the Layout folder which i inflate my views. In my Main.axml, I have a recyclerView declared to display the CardView in  the list.axml.

**Please note: MainActivity returns a setContentView(Resource.Layout.Main)**

Most of my designs are in the list.axml folder and i would want have to access the id's of some elements in the list.axml file and give them functions in my MainActivity.cs.

Now my question is Doesn't Xamarin provide a way to access elements in list.axml file from the MainActivity.cs?

**List.Axml Layout Folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:text="Caption"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:maxLines="50"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" 

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Main.axml- Layout Folder**

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main)
//finding the id of ImageView in list.axml
ImageView Img = FindViewById<Resource>(Resource.Id.ImageView)
```

Comment: Your CardView is available within your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, as there could can be multiple card views inflated by the `RecyclerView`, it does not make sense to try to FindingViewById, you of course can FindingViewById within your RecyclerView adapter/viewholder. Maybe you can provide more context to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @SushiHangover, i am not getting the id of the `RecycleView` but instead an element like the id of a TextView in my `list.axml`. I have added some codes to understand my context please :)

Comment: Is `list.axml` inflated within your `RecyclerView` adapter?

Comment: Yes. I have it inflated in my adapter alright

Comment: Then access it from within your RecyclerView adapter/viewholder

Comment: The adapter/viewholder doesn't take `FindViewById`

Comment: You might want to review how a RecyclerView works: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#RecyclerView_Helper_Classes